# What to do next?

Tags: magento2, admin, adminhtml, login

I fell in love with Magento first sight of me but I do not know how to confess
Please help me. I've installed Magento one click on Digital and I don't know what to do next.
How to login to admin start love magento?

Comment: Home Page
CMS homepage content goes here

Answer (score 0):

To find out the Magento 2 URI you can run the following command:

```
php bin/magento info:adminuri
```

Alternatively you can open `app/etc/env.php` and find the corresponding admin URI:

```
'backend' =>
  array (
    'frontName' => 'admin_1wgrah',
  ),
```

With the example above you can access your admin via http://your.domain.name/admin_1wgrah

Comment: But I can not be accessed with a password, I tried to log in with the file Zilla - Termanal - Win SCP will not work with the supplied password

Comment: Fabulous. It has worked
Thanks what has helped me

Comment: @jingling feel free to mark your question as answered so it'll benefit for others ;)